# Subreport in Jasper-Reports does not split

Tags: split, jasper-reports, subreport, page-break

I'm stuck with subreports in Jasper Reports. I'm using Jasper Reports 5.0.1, where I've designed a subreport within a subreport:

```
main-report
- detailband 1 => outer subreport

outer subreport
- detailband 1 => inner subreport
- detailband 2 => summary info
```

Everything works fine unless the content of the inner subreport grows too large to fit on one page. Instead of adding a page break the report just ends after page 1, even not printing the summary info in the next detail.

I'm a little confused about the whole options I can set in iReport. Which kind of combination of Split Type/Stretch Type/Position Type do I have to use to get that working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it working finally after playing for hours with the settings. For reference:

- all detail bands need *Split Type*=`Stretch`
- all sub report components need *Position Type*=`Fix Relative to Top`
- all sub report components need *Stretch Type*=`No stretch`
- all sub reports need to have set the report property *Ignore pagination*=`false` (unchecked)

Hope that this is of help to somebody else

Comment: Though I don't have the same problem but I never knew about Ignore pagination and that saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Also make sure not to use columns in the sub-report, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11559878/119937

Comment: For me it was about disabling "Keep together" option for a group.